# Asp.net core best practice example

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-6, inversion-of-control, solid-principles, loose-coupling

I was searching for an example that implement all the new principles in .net web development, i found a good one but it was for mvc4

visit http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3d39b4/crud-operations-using-the-generic-repository-pattern-and-dep/

The pattern that i'm searching for preferably using:
asp.net-core
EF6
code first
loose coupling
SOLID
IOC

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can find same article in ASP.NET Core MVC https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36655.onion-architecture-in-asp-net-core-mvc.aspx

Comment: thank u, i did implement the DIP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer the **ASP.NET Boilerplate** framework for that.I highly recommend to explore it.It's **Free** and **Opensource**.

It uses Dependency Injection frameworks as **Castle Windsor** and  **AutoMapper** as a mapper API.

You can learn following techniques and more ...

- Layered Architecture
- Domain Driven Design (DDD)
- Dependency injection (DI)
- Integration Testing
- Solid Architecture

**Here are the links :**

[ASP.NET Core MVC and EF 6](http://www.aspnetboilerplate.com/Templates)

[ASP.NET Core, Entity Framework Core and ASP.NET Boilerplate to Create NLayered Web Application](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1115763/Using-ASP-NET-Core-Entity-Framework-Core-and-ASP-N)

[ASP.NET Boilerplate documentation](http://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents)

Comment: Thank you, i will follow the article.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from above, you can also generate boilerplate using Yeoman 
         [Yeoman homepage](http://yeoman.io)